# Pull text from .txt file and display in .svg

Tags: text, svg, href

I am trying to have a SVG which pulls some text from a .txt file and displays it.
Here is my code so far.

```
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <text x="100" y="200" font-size="45" fill="red" >
    <tref xlink:href="sensors.txt"/>
  </text>

</svg>
```

I don't understand why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your non-functional `<tref>` elements, you can add a script to the end of the SVG that loads the desired text files via Ajax:

```
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="100" y="200" font-size="45" fill="red" >
    <tref xlink:href="sensors.txt"/>
  </text>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var trefs = document.getElementsByTagName("tref");
    for (var i=0; trefs[i]; i++) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET",trefs[i].getAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href"),false);
      xhr.send("");
      trefs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText),trefs[i]);
    }
  </script>
</svg>
```

Of course, this only works for referencing text files, as you do.  This could be stylistically refined and, if needed, also be made working for references of text via IDs, like `xlink:href="#textId'`, even for referenced IDs from external files, like `xlink:href="other.svg#textId"`.

I'm not sure whether it can sensibly be sniffed whether the browser already supports all needed aspects of `<tref>` to only run the script if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken your code is corresponding the specification.

It looks like `tref` element isn't commonly implemented (at least not in Firefox 17). In Chrome 23, although it renders example from spec quite well, it doesn't seem to work with text defined in external file (neither in plain text file nor external svg defs). I tried both absolute and relative linking and including a file protocol.

I guess you will have to insert the text using some scripting language like PHP if on server, otherwise it will be quite hard.

More about this element in spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TRefElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/tref

Comment: [This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=273171) tracks the status for Firefox (currently not implemented).